# Special Relativity - three body problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, particle-physics

I have a problem with solving three-body problem in special relativity. I know that in general this problem doesn't have good solution, but I have a specific case when it should be good answer.

Suppose we want to measure mass of (anti)neutrino by observing $^3$H decay:

$$^3\text H\to^3\text{He}+e^-+\bar\nu$$

We have mass of $^3$He, $^3$H and difference between maximal possible energy for theoretical calculations when $m_\nu=0$ and measured maximal electron energy $E_\text{exp}$.

I don't want this question to be a simple homework problem, so I ask - is there a good method for calculating even 1-dimensional kinematic relativity problem?

Comment: It's possible to do this as consecutive 2-body decays, i.e., ${}^3{\rm H}\to{}^3{\rm He}+\alpha$, $\alpha\to e^-+\bar\nu$.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I am dumb - right after posting this I found an easy way: because helium-3 and tritium are 3000 heavier than electron, we can set both of them as unmovable points. Change of mass $\Delta m=m_\text{3H}-m_\text{3He}$ will be energy of both electron and neutrino. I get four equations:

$$\Delta m=E_\text{exp}+E_\nu,$$
$$\Delta m=E_\text{th}+p_\nu^0,$$
$$p_e=p_\nu,\quad p_e^0=p_\nu^0,$$

where $^0$ is index for theoretical case of neutrino mass equal to zero.